# Panel heading is not full

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When I use the class `col-lg-6` on a `panel` in bootstrap, the `panel-heading` does not fill the width of the panel.

How can this be fixed?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="panel panel-default col-lg-6">
<div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
<div class="panel-body">
Panel content
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Easy fix. Move the col-lg-6 to a div tag that surrounds the panel as such:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading without title</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Panel content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By giving `col-lg-6` you are giving the panel the width specified in `col-lg-6`.Instead put the panel markup inside the div containing `col-lg-6`.

Here is the [live working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/6un4yftz/).

I am not sure if you want [this](http://jsfiddle.net/abhighosh18/6un4yftz/1/) too or not.